# space dash as delimiter for group match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to greedy match string and mark it is as group until it encounter space dash ( -). So far I've got:

`^ *-{2}([\w\d-]+)(=([ \w\d-]+))?(.*)|(.+)`

and my test string is:

```
--match1=match2
--match1=match2 match2
--match1=match2 match2-match2
--mat-ch1=match2 match2
--match1=match2-match2 match2
--match1=match2 -lastmatch
--match1=match2 --lastmatch
--match1 -lastmatch
--match1 --lastmatch
lastormatch
```

Every each kind of match (`match1`, `match2`, `lastmatch`, `lastormatch`) should be grouped together if they are next to each other. This is working for every line, except 6 and 7. Basically '`-`' should act as delimiter when it comes to `match2` group (but `-` surrounded by `/w/d` is fine as part of string inside group). I know, that lookahead/lookbehind should be used, but I can't get it right.

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2vdL.png) comparing to [what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXwpB.png)

regex101.com

Comment: You have not precised what exact group structure is expected for Cases 6 and 7.

Comment: --(match1)=(match2)( -lastmatch)
--(match1)=(match2)( --lastmatch)

let's say that here bracket shows where group should be.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you need. Please add explanations to the question

Comment: "should be grouped together, if they are ... marked as one group" Isn't that a tautology?

Comment: [What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2vdL.png) comparing to [what I need](http://i.imgur.com/XtKAf2R.png)

Comment: What about: [`^ *(?:--)?([\w-]+)(?:=((?:[\w-]| \w)+))?(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lOyUzG/2)

Comment: @trincot awesome sauce, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but based on your "what I need" picture this might be sufficient:

`^ *-{2}([\w\d-]+)(=(?:[\w\d-]| (?!-))+)?(.*)|(.+)`

By accepting either `[\w\d-]` or spaces not followed by - instead of `[ \w\d-]` it seems to work for you test data.

But without understanding exactly what your goal is there might be issues with a different data set.

Comment: The idea is to recognise parameters that are passed to the bash script, since I don't want to use getopts.

`^ *-{2}([\w\d-]+)(=((?:[\w\d-]| (?!-))+))?(.*)|(.+)` (one bracket more) worked exactly as I wanted.

Comment: @a_z Great! Glad you got it sorted. If you are looking to capture the different arguments then perhaps something along the lines of `(?:--?((?:[\w\d-]| (?!-))+)=?((?:[\w\d-]| (?![-]))+)?)|^([^-]+)$` could be relevant - https://regex101.com/r/NVgqNe/1

Comment: Idea is to match first potential option +optional input (like `-v` or `--log-file=logfile`) convert it to `verbose=true` or `log_file=logfile` inside bash, shift initial match from input array and iterate trough rest of input array. I'm not quite done with interpreting single dash options (like -q or -qwer with optional input) just yet, but I'm getting there :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash is a good post, but every answer is missing a bit or code is huge.

Answer (score 0):

[^ *(?:--)([\w-]+)(?:=((?:[\w-]| \w)+))?|(.*)](https://regex101.com/r/EwadbC/2) Is exactly what I need. Combined answers of @trincot and @rvalvik.